# Join two fft frequency spectra

Tags: numpy, audio, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I have two frequency maps obtained from numpy fft. Like so:

```
def fft(self):
    Y = np.fft.fft(self.data)  # fft computing and normalization
    Y = 2.0/self.len * np.abs(Y[:self.len//2])
    frq = np.arange(self.len) / self.duration # two sides frequency range
    X = frq[range(self.len//2)] # one side frequency range
    return FrequencyProfile(X, Y)
```

The bucket sizes of resulting frequency maps are different. I need to join them without losing the quality, because I use them for further sound generation.

I've tried bringing both to a standard bucket size:

```
# RESOLUTION is the size of the bucket, smaller than original
X1 = np.arange(int(np.min(X)), int(np.max(X)), RESOLUTION)
Y1 = np.interp(X1, X, Y)
```

And then subsequently add them like so:

```
def add(self, p):
    f = [self.min_f(), self.max_f(), p.min_f(), p.max_f()]
    # min_f, max_f return frequency extremes of the map
    f.sort()
    X = np.arange(f[0], f[3], RESOLUTION)
    Y1 = np.zeros_like(X)
    Y2 = np.zeros_like(X)
    i1 = int(np.round(self.X[0] / RESOLUTION))
    i2 = int(np.round(self.X[-1] / RESOLUTION)) + 1
    np.copyto(Y1[i1:i2], self.Y)
    i1 = int(np.round(p.X[0] / RESOLUTION))
    i2 = int(np.round(p.X[-1] / RESOLUTION)) + 1
    np.copyto(Y2[i1:i2], p.Y)
    Y = Y1 + Y2
    return FrequencyProfile(X, Y)
```

But the sound generated from the map differed greatly from the original, even though it looked right when plotted. Something was lost in the translation.

After searching all I could, I've failed to find a good solution.
Do you know of any?

Comment: You need to upsample the lower-resolution spectrum to the upper-resolution spectrum before adding, and then add in the complex domain. See e.g. [Sampling Rate Conversion in the Frequency Domain](https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/1588221/mod_folder/intro/fft-multirate.pdf) for upsampling.